# visual studio 2015 cordova build error local npm installation failed

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, npm

`Visual studio 2015`, `Cordova 6.5.0`. `xcode 8.3` and `ios 10.2`.

I was trying to debug cordova app for ios in local device . Everything was working fine. However I was in need of upgrade of vs-tac to install latest debug libraries to debug successfully. It suggested me to use "Clear Cordova Cache" to get latest vs-tac library for debugging the app in ios devices.

When I used "clear cordova cache", the whole world problems started, I have been held up at the following problem which I could not resolve in spite of all the suggested solutions.

I reinstalled nodejs. I cleared cache several times. I reinstalled cordova. I checked path and many more suggested steps I implemented but the errors stays the same.

Can anybody throw some light here!!

Error text:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v0.12.9

npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we

npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.

npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

 npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead

C:\Users\Ekambarrao\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli -> C:\Users\Ekambarrao\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd edge-cs@0.3.0 install C:\Users\Ekambarrao\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-    tac\node_modules\edge-cs

 node tools/install.js

 ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1

 ------ Package installation failed. Retrying...




C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(285,5): error : Error installing local npm package.

MSBUILD : cordova-build error : module.js:338

module.js:338

MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  throw err;

throw err;

MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  

MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Users\Ekambarrao\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.

 Error Cannot find     module 'C:\Users\Ekambarrao\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'

MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)

MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)

MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module.runMain     (module.js:501:10)

at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)

MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at startup (node.js:129:16)

at startup (node.js:129:16)

MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at node.js:814:3

at node.js:814:3

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Up grade your node js version Or install  latest version of node js

Comment: I did that nodejs installation thrice. Also Just now I repaired even visual studio. This is really driving me crazy. why one action collapses entire setup of vs!!!

Comment: which node version u installed  and don't install the version which  came with visual studio and  repairing the visual studio wont help much in this matter. i once faced this problem i downloaded node js installer from node site and installed and worked perfectly

Comment: the node was downloaded from nodejs.org and is the latest one. the following error can confirm the latest node js.  "Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 7.10.0 (x64) and npm."

Comment: one interesting observation, Visual Studio 2015 is installing by itself node 0.12.9 when I clear the cache and open the VS again.   -----------------------XXXX-------------- Third party software is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third party software. Third party software may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses.
Installing Node 0.12.9. This could take a few minutes...
Succeeded

Comment: Just now i installed node 6.10.. and installed vs2015 community and i  unchecked node 0.12.9 which came from vs 2015 so did u try to run the program again

Comment: where can I find option to uncheck that node 0.12.9?

Comment: While installing in features--> cross mobile platform development-->common tools and software developments kits--> <node>  here node will be located so while installing or modifying please uncheck it and install

Comment: I have vs 2015 professional, I could find "disabled" option for Joyant Nodejs. any alternative way to do this? I have been struggling to publish to ios since last one month and now stuck with corrupted build and fighting with build.

Comment: one more interesting observation, in options>>tools for apache cordova, two check boxes are there as automatically detect proxy settings and use sandboxed version of nodejs. I don't remember the sequence. I played with these then I got out of this error of not supporting node 0.12.9. What makes you end up in problem and what bails you out, only god knows.

Comment: @ekambarkodali I found that the item is disabled when the Joyent version from Visual Studio is not the installed version.  If you uninstall node from 'Add or remove programs' this item becomes enabled and unchecked.  Still doesn't resolve the issue of where this 0.12.9 version is coming from... I only have 7.10 installed.

Comment: Exact same thing happened to me. After clearing cordova cache to try to fix a problem where the debugger could not attach to android device anymore, nothing compiled anymore through vs2015. However, it builds fine using the ionic cli.